# Batch file internal data

Tags: batch-file, system, internal

I am trying to give my memory game a high score option that will save your score in itself and be call all the saved scores when you visit the "high score" section of the program.  The code i have so far is here:

```
@echo off
REM Produced by Calder Hutchins
REM This is a game
title Memory Game
:begin
set point=0
cls
echo.
echo Memeory Game
echo ------------------
echo 1) Play
echo 2) Instructions
echo 3) High Scores
echo ------------------
set /p pick=^>
if %pick%==1 goto one
if %pick%==2 goto two
if %pick%==3 goto three
goto begin
:one
cls
REM Determines the number
if %point% LSS 6  set /a rand=%random% %% (100 - 1 + 1)+ 1
if %point% LSS 12 if %point% GTR 5 set /a rand=%random% %% (500 - 100 + 1)+ 100
if %point% LSS 18 if %point% GTR 11 set /a rand=%random% %% (1000 - 500 + 1)+ 500
if %point% LSS 24 if %point% GTR 17 set /a rand=%random% %% (2000 - 1000 + 1)+ 1000
if %point% LSS 30 if %point% GTR 23 set /a rand=%random% %% (9000 - 1500 + 1)+ 1500
if %point% LSS 36 if %point% GTR 29 set /a rand=%random% %% (19000 - 5000 + 1)+ 5000
if %point% LSS 42 if %point% GTR 35 set /a rand=%random% %% (32000 - 10000 + 1)+ 10000
if %point% LSS 48 if %point% GTR 41 set /a rand=%random% %% (999 - 100 + 1)+ 100
if %point% LSS 48 if %point% GTR 41 set /a randtwo=%random% %% (999 - 100 + 1)+ 100
if %point% GTR 47 set /a rand=%random% %% (9999 - 1000 + 1)+ 1000
if %point% GTR 47 set /a randtwo=%random% %% (9999 - 1000 + 1)+ 1000
echo.
REM  Prints the number  
if %point% LSS 42 echo %rand% 
if %point% GTR 41 set rand=%rand%%randtwo%
if %point% GTR 41 echo %rand%
echo.
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /p yourOption=Guess:
REM Determines correct or wrong
if %youroption%==%rand% set /a point=%point% +1 & goto one
cls
echo.
echo You scored: %point%
echo.
set /p name=Type name:
echo %name%  -  %point% >> E:\Scripts\Batch\memoryGame\score.txt
goto begin
:two
cls
echo. 
echo The objective of the game is to get as many points as possible.  To get points you must correctly retype the numbers that appear on the screen.  The numbers show for a short period of time.  As you get more points the numbers get longer!  When you have lost you will be prompted to enter your name.  You can view the highscores too!  
echo. 
pause
goto begin
:three
cls
echo.
sort E:\Scripts\Batch\memoryGame\score.txt
echo.
pause
goto begin
```

The one above just saves to a file but i want it to save internally if it is possible.  I was given a script that i have modified but can find no way to implement in my game.  The code for the script is:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%D in ('findstr /R /N "storedData" "%~f0"' ) do set end_batch=%%D
echo Make data

echo echo data entry 4^>^>"%~f0"
echo(>>"%~f0"
echo data entry ^4>>"%~f0"

echo Print Data
type "%~f0" | more +%end_batch%
exit /b 0


:storedData
```

Any suggestions on how i can get it to work?

Comment: `sort E:\Scripts\Batch\memoryGame\score.txt`  you want to sort a batch file?

Comment: I used that so it would sort the entries names from A to Z.  Each line contains a name than their points that they got next to it.

Comment: What do you think goes on if you `sort` the batch code ?

Comment: What?  i'm not sorting batch code.  I'm sorting a text file independently from the batch file.

Comment: OK, what do you want to store in the batch file?

Comment: I want to store the data that would of been submitted to the external file to be stored in the batch file instead.  The data is the %name% and %point% that the user has.

Comment: I think you want this independently store in a text file for sorting?

Comment: @CalderHutchins wrote: "I was given a script that i have modified but can find no way to implement in my game". Why did you selected it as Best Answer then? ;)

Comment: I thought i could do it lol.  Turns out i could now.  I am a person who figures out stuff by experimenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm..
I have a better idea than my previous answer - alternate data streams(works only on NTFS):

```
    echo You scored: %point%
    echo.
    set /p name=Type name:
    echo %name%  -  %point% >>"%~f0:scores"
    goto begin
    :two
    cls
    echo. 
    echo The objective of the game is to get as many points as possible.  To get points you must correctly retype the numbers that appear on the screen.  The numbers show for a short period of time.  As you get more points the numbers get longer!  When you have lost you will be prompted to enter your name.  You can view the highscores too!  
    echo. 
    pause
    goto begin
    :three
   cls
   echo.
   more<"%~f0:scores" | sort
   echo.
   pause
   goto begin
```

But this will be literal sorting...

EDIT:

```
@echo off
REM Produced by Calder Hutchins
REM This is a game
title Memory Game
:begin
set point=0
cls
echo.
echo Memeory Game
echo ------------------
echo 1) Play
echo 2) Instructions
echo 3) High Scores
echo ------------------
set /p pick=^>
if %pick%==1 goto one
if %pick%==2 goto two
if %pick%==3 goto three
goto begin
:one
cls
REM Determines the number
if %point% LSS 6  set /a rand=%random% %% (100 - 1 + 1)+ 1
if %point% LSS 12 if %point% GTR 5 set /a rand=%random% %% (500 - 100 + 1)+ 100
if %point% LSS 18 if %point% GTR 11 set /a rand=%random% %% (1000 - 500 + 1)+ 500
if %point% LSS 24 if %point% GTR 17 set /a rand=%random% %% (2000 - 1000 + 1)+ 1000
if %point% LSS 30 if %point% GTR 23 set /a rand=%random% %% (9000 - 1500 + 1)+ 1500
if %point% LSS 36 if %point% GTR 29 set /a rand=%random% %% (19000 - 5000 + 1)+ 5000
if %point% LSS 42 if %point% GTR 35 set /a rand=%random% %% (32000 - 10000 + 1)+ 10000
if %point% LSS 48 if %point% GTR 41 set /a rand=%random% %% (999 - 100 + 1)+ 100
if %point% LSS 48 if %point% GTR 41 set /a randtwo=%random% %% (999 - 100 + 1)+ 100
if %point% GTR 47 set /a rand=%random% %% (9999 - 1000 + 1)+ 1000
if %point% GTR 47 set /a randtwo=%random% %% (9999 - 1000 + 1)+ 1000
echo.
REM  Prints the number  
if %point% LSS 42 echo %rand% 
if %point% GTR 41 set rand=%rand%%randtwo%
if %point% GTR 41 echo %rand%
echo.
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /p yourOption=Guess:
REM Determines correct or wrong
if %youroption%==%rand% set /a point=%point% +1 & goto one
cls
echo.
echo You scored: %point%
echo.
set /p name=Type name:
echo %name%  -  %point% >>"%~f0:scores"
goto begin
:two
cls
echo. 
echo The objective of the game is to get as many points as possible.  To get points you must correctly retype the numbers that appear on the screen.  The numbers show for a short period of time.  As you get more points the numbers get longer!  When you have lost you will be prompted to enter your name.  You can view the highscores too!  
echo. 
pause
goto begin
:three
cls
echo.
more<"%~f0:scores" | sort
echo.
pause
goto begin
```

Comment: When i try to run it with it added onto my script i get "the file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Comment: there are two things you should add `echo %name%  -  %point% >>"%~f0:scores` and `more<"%~f0:scores" | sort`  .Are you sure both are there?

Comment: I posted a edit on your post to what my code looks like now.  I did include what you put in.

Comment: with this command (requires administrator privileges) you can check if your file system is `NTFS`  :  `fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo c:`

Comment: I am running this off my USB, is that ok?

Comment: Could you try it on your hard.I'm not sure if USBs supports ADS. Especially if the usb is formated with FAT32 .It depends on the file system where is the .bat

Comment: USB is usually FAT32, not NTFS.

Comment: "The system can not find the file specified"  Could it be a problem with more<"%~f0:scores" | sort

Comment: The .bat is located now at... C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\memoryGame\testingGrounds.bat

Comment: you get the error when you play or when you display the high scores?

Comment: I get the error when i type "3" and press enter which leads me to more<"%~f0:scores" | sort

Comment: you need first to play a game and set some scores...The ADS does not exists if there is noting recorded there.

Comment: Ok it works! thankx.  But where does it save the values?  Nothing in the code changed.  And will the values reset if i move it to another computer?  And can i reset the values?

Comment: Saving the bat does remove its ADS (here).

Comment: @Calder Hutchins it is saved in something like alternative version of the file which not visible.The `MORE` command can read Alternative Data Streams , but for example `TYPE` or the notepad cannot . Here's more info : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(file_system)

Comment: @ Endoro - yes.Every edit of the code deleted the ADS (tested with Notepad++, but not with plain Notepad).But the copy works fine

Comment: Notepad - does not delete the ADS , only notepad++

Answer (score 2):

The Batch file below do exactly what you requested, that is, it will save your score in itself and be call all the saved scores when you visit the "high score" section of the program.

```
echo You scored: %point%
echo.
set /p name=Type name:
echo %name%  -  %point% >> "%~F0"
goto begin
:two
cls
echo. 
echo The objective of the game is to get as many points as possible.  To get points you must correctly retype the numbers that appear on the screen.  The numbers show for a short period of time.  As you get more points the numbers get longer!  When you have lost you will be prompted to enter your name.  You can view the highscores too!  
echo. 
pause
goto begin
:three
cls
echo.
for /F "delims=:" %%n in ('findstr /N "^:savedScores" "%~F0"') do set n=%%n
more +%n% "%~F0" | sort
echo.
pause
goto begin
:savedScores
```